# How do I convert this date vector into a Datetime to use it in visualization?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, datetime, time

[DataFrame overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyYtn.png)

Can someone help me how you would go around this and use the dates and the time to make visualisation for this? (for example time-brackets (9-12, 12-15, 15-18 and so on). Price against time. But since the format is kinda difficult I can't get the solution.

I tried this but it doesn't work (probably; because its a vector)

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

print "The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj)

print "The date is", date_time_obj
```

Comment: can you please provide a example with a code snippet instead of images? images should be included mainly to represent plots..

Comment: Ok thanks! I would like to do smth like this but it doesn't work:

Comment: from datetime import datetime


date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')


print "The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj)
print "The date is", date_time_obj

Comment: you can look at this to understand what i mean :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

date_time_str = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print('date_time_str',date_time_str)

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```